# select query from 3 tables using sum()

Tags: mysql, join, select, sum

I have 3 mysql tables. All the tables will have many entries of the same person.
For desire output need help

```
Table_1                               Table_2                             Table_3

id   name   bill                  id   name   total                  id   name   total                 
1    John   100                   1    John   20                     1    John   100
2    Kevin  50                    2    Tom    30                     2    Tom    20 
3    Tom    50                                                       3    Tom    30 
4    John   20



Output_Table
name   sum(bill)   sum(total)   sum(amount)
John   120         20           100
Kevin  50          null         null
Tom    50          30           50
```

Comment: What did you try, and why did that fail ?

Comment: Aggregate in subqueries then join.

Comment: P.S. there is no field `amount` in the three table you have shared with us.

Answer (score 1):

This is the test I did in [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bgr5NwBl). I think we can't determine which table contains all the names, for example, table_1 has Kevin, other tables don't, table_2 has Peter, other tables don't, so we need to look up all the names jointly, and then sum the data according to the name.

My sql looks bloated and complicated, but I hope it helps.

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  bill INT
);

CREATE TABLE table_2 (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  total INT
);

CREATE TABLE table_3 (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50),
  amount INT
);

insert into table_1 values
(1,'John',100),
(2,'Kevin ',50),
(3,'Tom',50),
(4,'John',20);

insert into table_2 values
(1,'John',20),
(2,'Tom',30),
(3,'Peter', 70);


insert into table_3 values
(1,'John',100),
(2,'Tom',20),
(3,'Tom',30);
```

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT name,
    (SELECT SUM(bill) FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.name = names.name) AS sum_bill,
    (SELECT SUM(total) FROM table_2 WHERE table_2.name = names.name) AS sum_total,
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table_3 WHERE table_3.name = names.name) AS sum_amount
FROM
    (
        SELECT name FROM table_1
        UNION
        SELECT name FROM table_2
        UNION
        SELECT name FROM table_3
    ) AS names;
```

| name | sum_bill | sum_total | sum_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 120 | 20 | 100 |
| Kevin | 50 | *null* | *null* |
| Tom | 50 | 30 | 50 |
| Peter | *null* | 70 | *null* |

Comment: As a suggestion, you can list the table sql and insert sql, and show the solution you tried. This will save the respondent time and prevent them from reworking the solution you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be as below query

```
SELECT t1.name, SUM(t1.bill) bill, sum(t2.total) total, sum(t3.total) amount  FROM Table_1 t1
FULL JOIN Table_2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
FULL JOIN Table_3 t3 on t3.name = t1.name 
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: Note that if there are names existing in t2 or t3, but not in t1, they will not be included in the result. (Poor sample data?)

Comment: I thing full join includes all the records.

Comment: Yes, it would. But I don't think MySQL implements it.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` the tables, where you have separate columns for bill, total and amount. `GROUP BY` the result:

```
select name, sum(bill), sum(total), sum(amount) 
from
(
  SELECT name, bill, null total, null amount FROM table_1
  union all
  SELECT name, null, total, null FROM table_2
  union all
  SELECT name, null, null, amount FROM table_3
) dt
group by name
```

Perhaps a pre-`GROUP BY` query will be faster:

```
select name, sum(bill), sum(total), sum(amount) 
from
(
  SELECT name, sum(bill) bill, null total, null amount FROM table_1 group by name
  union all
  SELECT name, null, sum(total), null FROM table_2 group by name
  union all
  SELECT name, null, null, sum(amount) FROM table_3 group by name
) dt
group by name
```